# put just the label on top in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add the `labels` on top and `limits` at bottom. For example

```
library(ggplot2)

xlabs <- paste(levels(iris$Species),"\n(N=",table(iris$Species),")",sep="")

ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=xlabs)
```

Is there a way to put just `N=` on top? If I use `scale_x_discrete(position = "top")`,everything goes on top which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dewey Dunnington [has suggested](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171#issuecomment-614084750) the following hack for secondary discrete axes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

guide_axis_label_trans <- function(label_trans = identity, ...) {
  axis_guide <- guide_axis(...)
  axis_guide$label_trans <- rlang::as_function(label_trans)
  class(axis_guide) <- c("guide_axis_trans", class(axis_guide))
  axis_guide
}

guide_train.guide_axis_trans <- function(x, ...) {
  trained <- NextMethod()
  trained$key$.label <- x$label_trans(trained$key$.label)
  trained
}

ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  guides(x.sec = guide_axis_label_trans(~ paste0("N = ", table(iris$Species))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>